# Basic regex PHP issue

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to grab the articleId which is formatted as follows:

```
    articleId=1234567
```

Here is the code I am using

```
    $regex = 'articleId\=[0-9]{7}';
    preg_match_all($regex,$data,$match);
    for ($i=0; $i< count($match[0]); $i++) {
        echo "".$match[1][$i]."]";
    }
```

I am receiving the following error:
preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

FWIW I am using 5.2.17

Comment: and now with my +1 for your well formulated and formatted question you are also able to vote up. Do this on helpful answers and good questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place delimiters in your regexp, like this:

```
$regex = '/articleId=[0-9]{7}/';
```

also, there is no need to escape equal sign

Comment: Perfect thank you, I also appreciate the note about the equal sign.

Comment: @Eric if this answer solved your problem (I know it does) you should accept it, see [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thats good behavior here and reward the answerer for his effort.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot your '/'

```
preg_match_all('/' . $regex . '/',$data,$match);
```

or alternatively

```
$regex = '/articleId\=[0-9]{7}/';
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you for the alternative solutions, it is much appreciated.